# What is right and what is wrong?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, tafseer, prophet-muhammad, quran-translation

I'm from Asian country. I don't know whether our traditions is the same or not. But I need to make sure what is actual bidaah? I learned Quran in my language 3 years ago. I convert as muslim after that. But now I've heard many traditions that is contradict to Quran, but people born as muslim said its okay to do it. Which is true? For example:

1. Finish Quran. or Khatam Quran ceremony.
   As far as I know, Prophet Muhammad never stop reading Quran till wafat. Quran is non stop guidance till our last breath. So why there's a traditions celebrating a person who finish reading it?
2. Celebrating Prophet Muhammad Birthday.
   From what I learn Sirah history, the other prophet before Muhammad SAW is also the truth messenger. But Prophet Muhammad never celebrated the birthday of other prophets before him. So why there's a tradition where we celebrate Prophet Muhammad birthday?

There's a lot of other traditions that I couldn't write.. sorry if my question offended anyone. I'm still new to this because from what I learn from Quran, and Prophet's history.. Quran is a guidebook. Not more than that..

After we received Quran, we should spread it to those who never know.. right? That's what Prophet did. Deliver Quran to others as a guidance. then why people born as a muslim use Quran other than a guide? For example, they say "you read this surah, then u will be smarter". Or they would say, "you read this to prevent ghost."

Is that what Prophet do with Quran? in Quran there's a saying, if we need help, pray to Allah. Allah is near. even nearer than our neck veins.. then why don't we just pray straight to Allah? if we scared to other things more than we scared Allah, then our Aqidah is destroyed right?

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: For religious matters I would advise to read the scholarly opinions. I suggest islamqa.info as a helpful site in this matter. They are on the conservative side of things, but they present their opinions with supported evidence from the Quran and Sunnah, and often show the opposing opinions as well.

Comment: This addresses the second part of your question: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1214/is-celebrating-the-mawlid-day-halal-or-haram. I suggest you limit your question to the first part.

Comment: The first question has also an answer [Sharing and reading quran](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46072/sharing-and-reading-quran)

Answer (score -1):

### What is right and what is wrong?

In the name of the kudos grace of Allah. First comes the realization of functionality and that of the process, and that of order, and that of the occurrence. Everything made through Allah functions.

### Right

Through the comparisons of the functionality that of the command of functionality and that of the occurrence. When the comparison and the occurrence God then the occurrence receives the commendation of righteousness.

### Wrong

Through the comparisons of the functionality that of the command of functionality and that of the occurrence. When the comparison and the occurrence Devil then the occurrence receives the condemnation of error.

### Wisdom

Through the comparisons of the functionality that of efficiency and effectiveness and making selection of function giving higher status.

### Faith

Stopping the comparisons of the functionality and seeing that every path of Allah leads to equality in the balance at the difficulty and at glory.

### Finishing Quran

Once the realization comes that Allah is one and that touch births touch and the eyes control touch, but that conversation births conversation bringing life because in conversation Allah gains his due glory. Indeed whoever has located this life should celebrate and should continue at remembering the opposition of the touch and the conversation and at remembering the opposition of the eyes and the hearing of others.

### Celebrating Prophet Muhammad's (PBUH) Birthday

Because life comes from celebrating the works of Allah. If those near choose the celebrating of Birthday's remember that it was Allah who gives birth for everyone, and it is always good celebrating the works of Allah.

### Spreading the Message

Because conversation overcomes the touch, and since the conversation involves the back and forth, and since it uses words coming from the lips. You can correct the Christian saying that the back and forth of conversation we call "breath" and those translators did indeed translate this word "breath" as "Spirit" since spirit defines the emotional type of conversation and that the words coming from the lips of mankind we call the "Son of Man" and those translators did indeed translate the "Isay" (BPUH) as "Jesus" (BPUH) and that if needed can reference Numbers 23:19 stating:

> God is not a man, that He should lie, Nor a son of man, that He should repent.

and that in the kudos Quran it does state

> ... He says to it, “Be!”– and it is!) [Surah Yasin:82)

And in the custom of the Jewish would translate as

> ... He says to it, “Lord!”– and it is!) [Surah Yasin:82)

### Pray Straight to Allah

Because when we pray it uses words coming from the lips that we call the "Son of Man" and because the "Son of Man" we named the Isay my-shiekh (BPUH) that Allah (the merciful) hears. Indeed say it as you can walk it and as within the will of Allah.

Peace Be On You, and whoever did read this.